# Imagem com 100% de largura

Tags: html, css

Tenho as seguintes declarações de CSS aplicadas a um elemento:

```css
.minhaClass {
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  height:560px;
  background:url(../imagens/corpo/imagen.jpg) repeat-x top center;
}
```

Isso vai acontecer em um site com topo, corpo e rodapé. No corpo eu quero que a minha imagem tenha as características do código de exemplo.

## Problema

Em monitores maiores que 1200px de largura, a imagem vai ficar repetindo a largura.

## Pergunta

Existe alguma técnica para deixar a imagem com a largura de 100% sem perder a qualidade da mesma?

Comment: Mas você quer 100% do tamanho original? ou do elemento que ela está contida?

Comment: @IsraelZebulon Essa imagem está dentro de uma div com width:100%;

Comment: background-image: url("Hands.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: block;
background-size: 100%;

Answer (score 16):

Uma alternativa para navegadores *modernos* é definir o tamanho da imagem que está a ser aplicada como fundo de um elemento fazendo uso da propriedade de CSS [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>.

Funciona a partir das seguintes versões de navegadores:

> Safari 3+
> Chrome QualquerUm+
> IE 9+
> Opera 10+
> Firefox 3.6+

## CSS [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) (cover)

```css
.minhaClass{
  background: url(../imagens/corpo/imagen.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

[**Exemplo no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/6ejv9/)

[image: Captura de Tela]

De notar que na imagem, estamos a declarar `no-repeat` para que a mesma não se repita quando a largura do elemento é maior que a mesma.

Contudo, ao aplicarmos a propriedade `background-size` com o valor `cover`, estamos a dizer ao navegador que a imagem é para ocupar toda a dimensão do elemento.

#### Potencial problema

Se a imagem não estiver à escala do próprio elemento, a mesma vai ficar cortada pelo lado que desobedece à escala (ver o exemplo no link em cima).

---

## CSS [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) (100% 100%)

Se o objectivo é que a imagem fique rigorosamente 100% de largura e 100% de altura, então podemos utilizar:

```css
.minhaClass{
  background: url(../imagens/corpo/imagen.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Isto vai forçar a imagem a ficar com o mesmo tamanho do elemento onde se encontra aplicada.

[**Exemplo no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/6ejv9/1/)

[image: Captura de Tela]

---

**Dita:** Redimensiona a janela do resultado no JSFiddle para verificares que a imagem vai acompanhando o aumento ou diminuição da largura do elemento.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi, sua dúvida é como definir a largura de uma imagem via CSS de forma que ela tenha 100% do tamanho do seu elemento pai. Uma forma simples seria assim:

**HTML:**

```
<img src="imagem.png" class="largura-cheia">
```

**CSS:**

```
.largura-cheia{
    width:100%;
    height:560px;
}
```

Comment: Consegui deixar o width da imagem 100% com essa propriedade:

background-size:cover;

Assim sua largura ficou 100% e sua altura ajustável de acordo com o layout.

Obrigado a todos!
E desculpa pela pergunta, ficou um pouco complicado de entender :)

E parabéns ao site! Nota infinita!

Comment: Obrigado, caso você tenha achado a resposta para sua pergunta fora das respostas aqui postadas, você pode clicar no botão no final da página e responder sua própria pergunta, ajudando assim outras pessoas que possam vir a ter a mesma dúvida que a sua no futuro.

Answer (score 0):

Isso depende, queres que fique 100% no navegador ou no elemento que ela esta dentro?

Ele vai abrir 100% dentro do elemento pai, por exemplo:

```
<div style="width: 400px">
  <img src='img/img.jpg' style='width: 100%'>
</div>
```

A imagem vai ficar com 100% do elemento pai que é 400px.

Pra pegar 100% do browser, nesse exemplo de cima o elemento pai tinha que ter 100% também de width.

```
<div style="width: 100%">
  <img src='img/img.jpg' style='width: 100%'>
</div>
```

Entendeste?